# difference between class="col" and class="col-xs/sm/md/lg-6"

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm just wondering the specifications of .col. I thought .col just meant it equally put all elements on the same row... but my code is pushing my third element on a different row. How come? (I'm using Bootstrap 4.)

```
<section class="portfolio colored-block" id="portfolio">
    <div>
        <h2>Portfolio</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <img src="http://qlip.in/images/YMCA-Realtor-Donation-3.jpg">
                <p>Consequat et ex sunt sunt cupidatat amet. Magna ad nostrud aute officia fugiat. Veniam consequat ex pariatur ex esse laboris non laboris in duis laboris consectetur ullamco nulla. Click <a href="#">here</a> for more information.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <img src="http://qlip.in/images/YMCA-Realtor-Donation-3.jpg">
                <p>Consequat et ex sunt sunt cupidatat amet. Magna ad nostrud aute officia fugiat. Veniam consequat ex pariatur ex esse laboris non laboris in duis laboris consectetur ullamco nulla. Click <a href="#">here</a> for more information.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <img src="http://qlip.in/images/YMCA-Realtor-Donation-3.jpg">
                <p>Consequat et ex sunt sunt cupidatat amet. Magna ad nostrud aute officia fugiat. Veniam consequat ex pariatur ex esse laboris non laboris in duis laboris consectetur ullamco nulla. Click <a href="#">here</a> for more information.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough room for the images so the cols wrap. Use img-fluid on the images so that they scale responsively...

https://www.codeply.com/go/RL7FuDXZ7X

```
   <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="http://qlip.in/images/YMCA-Realtor-Donation-3.jpg">
                <p>Consequat et ex sunt sunt cupidatat amet. Magna ad nostrud aute officia fugiat. Veniam consequat ex pariatur ex esse laboris non laboris in duis laboris consectetur ullamco nulla. Click <a href="#">here</a> for more information.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="http://qlip.in/images/YMCA-Realtor-Donation-3.jpg">
                <p>Consequat et ex sunt sunt cupidatat amet. Magna ad nostrud aute officia fugiat. Veniam consequat ex pariatur ex esse laboris non laboris in duis laboris consectetur ullamco nulla. Click <a href="#">here</a> for more information.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="http://qlip.in/images/YMCA-Realtor-Donation-3.jpg">
                <p>Consequat et ex sunt sunt cupidatat amet. Magna ad nostrud aute officia fugiat. Veniam consequat ex pariatur ex esse laboris non laboris in duis laboris consectetur ullamco nulla. Click <a href="#">here</a> for more information.</p>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Primary difference between "col" and the others is that when only "col" is specified, all of the columns in the row won't stack. They will be side by side no matter the width of the browser. By specifying the breakpoint (sm, md, etc.), it essentially tells the columns when to wrap. By specifying a number, it essentially tells the columns to wrap whenever they must so as to maintain a minimum width (6 for 50%, 4 for 33%, etc).